# Why does $\lim_{x\to\infty} (-1)^x$ involve complex numbers and natural exponential?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I was curious and I just put this limit into mathematica and found out an unusual answer so I was wondering if anybody could tell me why is $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (-1)^x=e^{2i0 \; \textrm{to} \; pi} \ ?$$

Thank you.

Comment: How do you define $(-1)^x$ when $x$ is not an integer?

Comment: is the related to $z=x+iy=re^{i\theta}$ ? Or am I completely off?

Comment: wait $(-1)^{non integer}$ is a complex number, $(-1)^{odd number}$ is $-1$ and $(-1)^{even number}$ is $1$ but I can't really classify $\infty$ as any of those.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(-1)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{i\pi})^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{i\pi x}=undefined$$

Comment: Ah i didn't see it that way. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: this limit does not exist in the normal sense of a limit e.g. $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0.$$

Now: if $x$ is an integer, we can easily say $(-1)^x=\begin{cases} 1, & x~\text{even} \\ -1, & x~\text{uneven}\end{cases}$. But already for $x\in\mathbb Q$ we have problems with that term, as e.g. $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\stackrel{?}{=}\sqrt{-1}$. This becomes even more complicated when we allow $x\in\mathbb R$.  Thus by limiting ourselves to the real numbers, we can't define $(-1)^x$ for $x\in\mathbb R$.

This is not a problem when we are allowing complex numbers. For $a\in\mathbb C^*$ and $z\in\mathbb C$ one defines $$a^z:=\exp(z \operatorname{Log}(a))$$ with $\operatorname{Log}$ being the complex logarithm. This is fairly similar to $a^x=\exp(x\ln(a))$ with $a>0,x\in\mathbb R$, which you should know as the definition for exponentiation where the exponent can be any real number. There are still some problems one has to talk about (mainly because there are different branches of the complex logarithm and one has to define which branch $\operatorname{Log}$ refers to), but now one can talk about $(-1)^x$ with $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: hm I see. Thanks for help!